# Option to Close the Questions is not appearing

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

There seems to be an close option for questions.

The question gets closed if it gets 5 votes for closing. The problem is, I am not seeing this option for every question (Even for the questions, whose answers has been accepted by the person who asked the question). I can see this for just the questions I have asked.

Is this because of some permission based on the reputation points? Or I am missing something?

Comment: You need [3000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have 3000 or more rep to be able to cast close votes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)